# Many to Many persistence JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to persist entities using JPA.
I have 2 entities with many to many relationship and I want to be able to do all crud operation on both sides.

**Here is a sample of my tables:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workflow_tasks")
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class WorkflowTaskEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String workflowTaskId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name="workflow_tasks_workflow_tasks_settings",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_task_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "setting_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<WorkflowTaskSettingEntity> settings;
...
}
```

**On the other side:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workflow_task_settings")
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class WorkflowTaskSettingEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String workflowTaskSettingId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "settings",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Set<WorkflowTaskEntity> workflowTasks;
}
```

Here is a repository interface implemented:

```
public interface WorkflowTaskSettingRepository
        extends CrudRepository<WorkflowTaskSettingEntity, Long> {
    Page<WorkflowTaskSettingEntity> findAll(Pageable pageRequest);
    List<WorkflowTaskSettingEntity> findAll();
    WorkflowTaskSettingEntity findByWorkflowTaskSettingId(String workflowTaskSettingId);

    WorkflowTaskSettingEntity findByValue(String name);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM WorkflowTaskSettingEntity c WHERE c.id = :id")
    void deleteById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

**Here is the different cases I have to handle:**

- Create WorkflowTaskSettingEntity and WorkflowTaskEntity objects in one shot
- Create WorkflowTaskSettingEntity and link it to several WorkflowTaskEntity objects
- Create WorkflowTaskSettingEntity and link it to several WorkflowTaskEntity
- Delete a relation between both tables
- Delete WorkflowTaskSettingEntity and relations
- Delete WorkflowTaskEntity and relations

**My first issue when i create an entry is that i don't persist all relations:**

I created first :

- 4 entries of WorkflowTaskEntity
- I try to persist 10 WorkflowTaskSettingEntity objects linked to the 4 entries I created
- The first WorkflowTaskSettingEntity is correctly persisted

[image]

**When persisting the second object it becomes weird:**
In theory I should have:

```
1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, 2-4 ...
```

and so on... but the result is the following.

[image]

**My second issue concerns performance and code length :**
I log my SQL queries and note that there are too many SQL queries for a basic select and insert. I also wonder why I have issues with detached entities and do have to persist a single object twice... It seems that my entities mapping is not as it should be.

**For creation I have the following code:**

```
@Override
public WorkflowTaskSettingDto create(WorkflowTaskSettingDto workflowTaskSettingDto) {
    Set<WorkflowTaskDto> workflowTaskDtos = workflowTaskSettingDto.getWorkflowTasks();
    WorkflowTaskSettingEntity workflowTaskSettingEntity = modelMapper.map(
            workflowTaskSettingDto, WorkflowTaskSettingEntity.class);

    workflowTaskSettingEntity.setWorkflowTasks(null);
    workflowTaskSettingEntity = repository.save(workflowTaskSettingEntity);
    Set<WorkflowTaskEntity> workflowTaskEntities = getWorkflowTasks(workflowTaskDtos);
    workflowTaskSettingEntity.addWorkflowTasks(workflowTaskEntities);
    workflowTaskSettingEntity = repository.save(workflowTaskSettingEntity);

    return modelMapper.map(workflowTaskSettingEntity, WorkflowTaskSettingDto.class);
}

private Set<WorkflowTaskEntity> getWorkflowTasks(Set<WorkflowTaskDto> workflowTaskDtos) {
    Set<WorkflowTaskEntity> workflowTaskEntities = new HashSet<>();
    workflowTaskDtos.forEach(workflowTaskDto -> {
        WorkflowTaskEntity workflowTaskEntity =
                appService.workflowTaskService().getById(workflowTaskDto.getWorkflowTaskId());
        if (workflowTaskEntity == null) {
            WorkflowTaskDto create = appService.workflowTaskService().create(workflowTaskDto);
            workflowTaskEntity = appService.workflowTaskService().getById(create.getWorkflowTaskId());
        }
        workflowTaskEntity.setSettings(workflowTaskEntity.getSettings());
        workflowTaskEntities.add(workflowTaskEntity);
    });
    return workflowTaskEntities;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time i made many-2-many in java was about 5 years ago as I'm avoiding such things but as far as I remember you need to define an intermediate table

you called `"workflow_tasks_workflow_tasks_settings"`

```
@Entity
@IdClass(WorkflowTasksSettingsMappingIds.class) // nice to add some id on these two i believe
@Table(name = "workflow_tasks_workflow_tasks_settings")
public class WorkflowTasksWorkflowTasksSettings {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "workflow_task_id")
    private String workflowTasksId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "setting_id")
    private String settingId;

  
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_task_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private WorkflowTaskEntity taask;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "setting_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private WorkflowTaskSettingEntity setting;

// getters setters

}
```

and ID

```
@Embeddable
public class ArticleOwnerId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "workflow_task_id")
    private String workflowTaskId;

    @Column(name = "setting_id")
    private String settingId;

  //getters setters
}
```

that's my guess

Comment: intermediate table is generated as expected. My issue is that values are not stored as expected

Comment: @davidvera i've got it, but to be honest I'd look for a problem in the logic(in these mappers you have etc.). Without seeing requests or whatever is invoking this code you had it;d be difficult to answer your question. Have you verified if everything looks as expected in memory?
My proposal would help with the second issue i believe.

With select's you can have an n+1 problem, but i rejected is as you used EAGER. My guess is that JPA loses the point somehow, but ofc. i didn't see code that fetches data. Also hard to say

Comment: @davidvera What comes to detached entities - just read about hibernate entity lifecycle. There are tones of articles